# The length of the string exceeds the value set on the maxJsonLength property

Tags: javascript, asp.net, javascriptserializer

Error during serialization or `deserialization` using the `JSON` `JavaScriptSerializer`. The length of the string exceeds the value set on the `maxJsonLength` property.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function pageLoad(sender, e) {
    var Indexproductgroup = $get('<%=cboproductgroup.ClientID %>').selectedIndex;
    var Selectedproductgroup = $get('<%=cboproductgroup.ClientID   %>').options[Indexproductgroup].value;

    var q = $find("autoCompleteBehavior2");
    q.add_populating(function() {
      q.set_contextKey(Selectedproductgroup);
    });
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your web.config, you must set the maxJsonLength property to a higher value.

```
<configuration> 
   <system.web.extensions>
       <scripting>
           <webServices>
               <jsonSerialization maxJsonLength="2147483644"/>
           </webServices>
       </scripting>
   </system.web.extensions>
</configuration>
```

Comment: In the page_load (code behind not in javascript) you could try to overwrite the MaxJsonLength of JavascriptSerializer class, something like this:

JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
serializer.MaxJsonLength = Int32.MaxValue;

Comment: i tried this Dim serializer As New JavaScriptSerializer()
        serializer.MaxJsonLength = Int32.MaxValue       but same error occured.....

Comment: Can you update your question with your code?

You need to overwrite the MaxJsonLength inside the function where is populating the data.